# Proof for linearly independent set that is compound of linear transformations...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We have $f:V\rightarrow V$ such that $v\in V$, $f^3(v) = 0$ and $f^2(v) \neq 0$. With that, prove that the set $S$ below are L.I:
$$
S = \left\{ v, f(v), f^2(v) \right\} 
$$

My answer:

For $S$ being L.I, we need to prove that $\alpha = \beta = \gamma =0 $:
$$
\alpha \cdot  v + \beta \cdot  f(v) + \gamma \cdot f^2(v) = 0
$$

I know that a proof for it being a L.I set would be possible if I kept applying the transformation $f$ in the equation above, and by deffinition that  $f^3(v) = 0$ I would get that the scalars needs to be $0$.

But I haven't done that in my test... Here's what I've done (idk if it's correct), and I really don't know why I thought like that...

Since the linear transformation $f$ maps $V$ to $V$, I can affirm that $f^2(v) = f(f(v))$ so the $f$ compound with $f$ is going to be a inverse linear function, ensuring that $f$ is isomorphic.

Because it's isomorphic, if I get $v \neq 0$ I'll have $f(v) \neq 0$ since only $f(0) = 0$.

Therefore, because it's injective: $\alpha = \beta = \gamma =0 $

How much points would you give me? This was a 7 point question.

Thanks...

Comment: How did you conclude that $f$ is invertible? The fact that $f(f(v))\ne 0$ is not enough to conclude that $f$ is invertible. You haven't demonstrated that $f$ is injective or surjective.

Comment: Beucase $f$ is a transformation that maps $V$ to $V$. So, $f(f(v))$ is taking the $V$  from image to $V$ of domain.

Comment: Just because $f$ has codomain $V$ and domain $V$ is not enough to conclude that $f$ is invertible.

Comment: But we can apply $f$ to $f$ again, making the compound of $f$. and because of the codomain $V$ and domain $V$, this $f^2(v)$, at least in my head, was going to be the inverse of $f$... I'm wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion that $f$ is invertible is not justified. Consider the orthogonal projection onto a line spanned by a vector $v\in\Bbb R^3$, $\operatorname{proj}_v:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$, for example. It is the case that $\operatorname{proj}_v\circ\operatorname{proj}_v = \operatorname{proj}_v^2$, but $\operatorname{proj}_v$ is not invertible.

Comment: Got it :/ so it's going to be 0 in 7 in that question. Thanks!!